# Ruby on Rails: how to work with multiple models and has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I can't solve my problem for already a week.

I have 4 models: **Person**, **Position**, **Workspace**, and **Phonenumber**.

The hierarchy is **Person > Position > Workspace > Phonenumber**.

A chain of all 4 models is unique. 
Say, there may be only **one** man:

```
Person | Position | Workspace   | Phonenumber |
Smith    Engineer  Department #4    555-666
```

But there may be another man with the same Position, Workspace, and Phonenumber:

```
Person | Position | Workspace     | Phonenumber |
Johnson  Engineer   Department #4     555-666
```

Or even the same Mr. Smith, but different position or workspace.

```
Person | Position | Workspace     | Phonenumber |
Smith    Engineer   Department #7     555-666
```

And so on.

All 4 at the same time are unique.

I want to store this data. I tried many different things. Nothing helped me at 100%.
For now my best idea is to use **has_many through** relationships with join model called **Employee**:

```
person_id | position_id | workspace_id | phonenumber_id
```

But how do I work with data?

Say, I want to create new person with some position, workspace and phonenumber. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you need a seperate Model for each of these entities? They seem like they could be attributes of a single model with a composite unique key.

Comment: I don't want to denormilize DB. Is a single model the only way here?

Comment: Doesn't a standard hierarchical relationship work? Such as Person has_many positions, Postion has_many workspaces, etc. Then to create a new person is standard association work: `@person = Person.create(...)`, `@person.position << Position.new(...)`, `@person.position.workspace << Workspace.new(...)`, etc. Or as @jmc suggested, flatten it out a little (you may not need that many layers). Maybe if you gave an example of what you've tried, we can tell what the problem is you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your setup in a Rails 4 application:

```
rails g model Person last_name
rails g model Position job_title
rails g model Workspace name
rails g model Phonenumber number
rails g model Employee person_id:integer position_id:integer workspace_id:integer phonenumber_id:integer
```

**app/models/person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :positions, :through => :employees
  has_many :workspaces, :through => :employees
  has_many :phonenumbers, :through => :employees

  validates :last_name, 
            :presence => true  
end
```

**app/models/employee.rb**

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :position
  belongs_to :workspace
  belongs_to :phonenumber

  validates :person, :position, :workspace, :phonenumber, 
            :presence => true

  validates :person_id,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => { :scope => [ :position_id, :workspace_id, :phonenumber_id ]}
end
```

Now to create a new `Person` with everything:

```
Person.create(:last_name => 'Smith').employees.where(:position => Position.where(:job_title => 'Engineer').first_or_create, :workspace => Workspace.where(:name => 'Department #8').first_or_create, :phonenumber => Phonenumber.where(:number => '555-666').first_or_create).first_or_create
```

To create an other `Position` for this Smith:

```
Person.where(:last_name => 'Smith').last.employees.where(:position => Position.where(:job_title => 'Admin').first_or_create, :workspace => Workspace.where(:name => 'Department #8').first_or_create, :phonenumber => Phonenumber.where(:number => '555-667').first_or_create).first_or_create
```

`first_or_create` searches for the entry or creates a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I edited your example a bit for my case. It works like a charm!
I can't understand why didn't I get it by myself? It's so obvious. =)